# Rails, current_page?(user_path) giving an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have element witch I want hide on specific pages, for example on pages located at `app/views/users/` (there I have `new.html.erb`; `edit.html.erb`; `show.html.erb`. And I have div in my `layouts/application.html.erb` it will be shown on all pages, so I want to hide it.

I thought i can do it like this:

```
<% unless current_page?(new_user_path) || current_page?(user_path) %>
  <div>Some content</div>
<% end %>
```

But it will give me an error, pretty obvious: for user_show method he need an id of the user, but we are not visiting pages where variable `@user` is present. Can you land me a help:

1. Any possibility to get around this error? (And I don't want to assign @user variable every where and I don't want make list of all page what are allowed)
2. Is there any other way to hide element on specific pages?

Comment: Have you tried this? If yes, can you please provide the error details ?

Comment: `current_page(user_path)` or `current_page?(user_path)` a missing `?`

Comment: @Ravi Mariya just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but this is how you can guard from user not being present:

```
unless current_page?(new_user_path) || @user && current_page?(user_path(@user))
```

Comment: You get the point. Sorry english is not my home language, so must be I did't told my problem the right way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that this will only work for the show and new actions, not for e.g. edit, since you have to explicitly include it with `current_page?(edit_user_path(@user))`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you probably want is:

```
<% unless current_page?(controller: 'users') %>
  <div>Some content</div>
<% end %>
```

By passing `controller: 'users'` you catch all routes (actions) for that controller, including the new/edit/show routes.

For more detail see the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F).

Comment: Not bad, I will keep this in mind and probably use it. Thank you!